# is there a better way to extract the data from the output using python code

Tags: python

I'm writing a newbie python code to find list of softwares installed on a system from which I will be running the code from. if the software is not installed, i'm planning to say that to the user.

The output will be something like this: (dpkg -l)

```
A snippet below:
----------------

ii  git                                    1:1.7.9.5-1                             fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
ii  git-man                                1:1.7.9.5-1                             fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (manual pages)


c = subprocess.Popen(['dpkg','-l'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
list_of_packages,error = c.communicate()
for item in list_of_packages.split('\n'):
    print item.split('ii')[-1]
```

which splits and Looks like i will have to apply few more splits to get the required data.
git and 1.7.9.5(version name).

I'm just trying to figure out if there is a better way of achieving this.

please advice..

Thanks,
-Vijay

Answer (score 6):

Trying to parse human-readable output is fragile, as you've observed.  Fortunately you can replace with `dpkg -l` with `dpkg-query -W -f='${Package}\t${Version}\n'` which is designed to produce machine-readable output.  See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg-query.1.html for full list of options to `dpkg-query`.

```
>>> args = ["dpkg-query", "-W", "-f=${Package}\t${Version}\n"]
>>> out, err = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
>>> print out #output is summarized, clearly
git     1:1.7.9.5-1
git-man 1:1.7.9.5-1
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.But I'm finding hard time to see its usage.       c = subprocess.Popen(['dpkg-query -W -f=\'${Package}\t${Version}\n\''],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE) This does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg -l` outputs lines not containing `ii`. And there are possibly packages containing `ii` in their name.

I would do it this way:

```
for item in list_of_packages.splitlines():
    if item.startswith('ii'):
        print item[4:]
```